# Are there environment variables for CMake add_library(<lib> OBJECT <src>)?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, shared-libraries

CMake is 2.8.8 introduced the OBJECT library type when compiling: add_library( OBJECT ).  It's a useful construct to be able to compile all classes to .o files, but don't add them to a library yet.

However, I'm not certain what flags it ends up attaching to the command in the generated make files.  Basically, when doing a add_library( SHARED ) command, it adds in any flags specified by CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CXX_FLAGS.  I'd like to be able to specify build flags for JUST the OBJECT libraries, without having to resort to the more global flags such as CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE.  Does anyone have any ideas if such a flag exists or is planned?

Recap:

```
# has CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CXX_FLAGS to set SHARED library build flags
add_library(<lib> SHARED <srcs>)

# Is any environment variable available to set OBJECT library build flags?
add_library(<lib> OBJECT <srcs>)
```

I was expecting an environment variable like CMAKE_OBJECT_LIBRARY_CXX_FLAGS to set the OBJECT build flags.  Looking through the source (Modules/SystemInformation.in and Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake), I didn't find anything that looked like it was specific to OBJECT libraries.

**Edit:**
Specifically, I want to add -fPIC to the OBJECT library, but not to the executables, which is why I don't want to specify the flag in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using CMake 2.8.9 or later, use the property [POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE.html) to enable position independent code in a compiler independet way:

```
add_library(<lib> OBJECT <srcs>)
set_target_properties(<lib> PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```

For older versions of CMake, you can set the [COMPILE_FLAGS](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_FLAGS) property of the `OBJECT_LIBRARY` target:

```
add_library(<lib> OBJECT <srcs>)
set_property(TARGET <lib> PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS "-fPIC")
```

Comment: This worked as expected and I was able to remove -fPIC from the environment-level compile flags.  Thanks!